# Dropdown Menu Different Levels

Tags: html, css

I want to create a Dropdown menu where I have 3 level, I have done the typical one work, When I hover on the main items I can see the second level items. Now the problem is that I can also see the third level items, Im looking to make the third level items only be seen when I hover the second level items to make it nicer. I took code from http://www.alistapart.com/articles/horizdropdowns/ and modified it.

Here is my file.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css_menu.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="menu">
    <ul class="formato"> 
        <li class="n-dos"><a class="menu" href="#">Home</a></li> 
        <li class="n-dos"><a class="menu" href="#">About</a> 
          <ul class="test"> 
            <li class="n-tres"><a class="menu" href="#">History</a></li> 
                <ul class="variacion">
                    <li><a class="menu" href="#">Ejemplo_1</a></li>
                    <li><a class="menu" href="#">Ejemplo_2</a></li>
                </ul>   
            <li class="n-dos"><a class="menu" href="#">Team</a></li> 
            <li class="n-dos"><a class="menu" href="#">Offices</a></li> 
          </ul> 
        </li> 
        <li class="n-dos"><a class="menu" href="#">Services</a> 
          <ul class="test"> 
            <li class="n-dos"><a class="menu" href="#">Web Design</a></li> 
            <li class="n-dos"><a class="menu" href="#">Internet Marketing</a></li> 
            <li class="n-dos"><a class="menu" href="#">Hosting</a></li> 
            <li class="n-dos"><a class="menu" href="#">Domain Names</a></li> 
            <li class="n-dos"><a class="menu" href="#">Broadband</a></li> 
          </ul> 
        </li>
        <li  class="n-dos"><a class="menu" href="#">Contact Us</a> </li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my CSS:

```
.formato
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.n-dos
{
    display:inline;
    background-color:black;
}
.n-tres
{
    display:inline;
    background-color:black;
}
.test
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px;
    top: 35px;
    display: none;
}
.variacion
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 120px;
    display: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.menu
{   
    float:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    background-color:#000000;
    padding:0.3em 0.6em;
    text-align:center;
    width: 150px;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
}
li.n-dos:hover ul.test 
{ 
    display:inline;
}
li.n-tres:hover ul.variacion 
{ 
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: If you can, include a live link. You may get better help.

Comment: http://nicashop.freeiz.com/menu.html

Comment: You shouldn't use underscores `_` in your CSS selectors, use hyphens `-` instead.

Comment: Thank you, '_' changed for '-'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the error, I feel dumb, it was a closing li tag in the wrong place. 
In the HTML file in the line:

```
<li class="n-tres"><a class="menu" href="#">History</a></li>
```

shouldn't be there since that list element had a sublist inside, thats why it didn't showed the sublist elements cause because of the wrong `</li>` it was like there were no elements inside the list

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you don't want to set element level selectors for these things. With selectors like

```
li ul 
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px;
    top: 35px;
    display: none;
}
```

and

```
ul li a 
{   
    float:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    background-color:#000000;
    padding:0.3em 0.6em;
    text-align:center;
    width: 150px;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
}
```

your style rules are *way* too specific. This is the kind of thing you should definitely handle with class selectors. BTW, if you don't make your anchor tags display:block, you're not going to get rules like width and padding and text-align etc. to behave.

Comment: Thaks for advince I changed those to classes but the problem I asked for remains, how can I set that the third level becomes visible "only" when Im over the second level of the nested list?

Comment: I'd need to see it in action. Not clear to me what you are talking about.

Comment: nicashop.freeiz.com/menu.html as you can see when I hover on "About" it not only shows me the next level which is 'History'-'Team'-'Offices' but also shows me the next level 'Ejemplo_1'-'Ejemplo_2' I dont want that to happen I want 'Ejemplo_1'-'Ejemplo_2'to be shown when I hover on 'History'.

Comment: Don't use n_dos for all the li elements. That's your problem. Give them a different class name and make the hover of the n_dos state turn those on. You only want them to turn on when you're over the 2nd menu, so  you're forgetting that the way your CSS is written it will display all descendants on hover of the main menu item.

Comment: I have tried but when I do that the next level is not shown, as you can see I used n_tres on the li that goes with "History" which is supossed to make third level of the menu visible, also I added a new line on the CSS li.n_tres:hover ul.variacion {display:block;} all should be set but it doesnt do anything... so I guess there is either a problem with the syntax or with my logic.